# Converting Fox Pro script to SQL

Tags: sql-server-2014, visual-foxpro

The goal is to convert a Fox Pro script to SQL. At the moment, we import the items into Fox Pro and then subdivide and manipulate according to a script that was developed 12 years ago.

It starts out like this

```
use xyz4digit.dbf
Append from S:/file location
Append from S:/2 - file location
```

From there, xyz4digit is built by appending various files. The same is done for 2, 3, 5, and 6 digit. Prior to this, we have 6 blank databases with identical structure. xyz4digit, 2, 3, 5, 6, and result.

Basically, I want to know if there is a process like this in SQL. The blank databases are on my local machine if this helps.

Comment: Well, to convert it to something else you first need to understand what the FoxPro script doesn. Start by learning that and continue from there. The `use` portion opens `xyz4digit.dbf`, and then each `append` adds data to it from the location specified as `S:/something`.  Now figure out how to perform the same operations in SQL. The equivalent to `append` is `INSERT INTO ...FROM`.

Comment: xyz4digit, 2 digit, 3 digit, and so on are all blank databases. In the script, each has a custom list of files appended to it. What is the SQL equivalent of use xyz4digit.dbf (again realizing that SQL does not use .dbf files)

Comment: There is no equivalent. It would be the `INTO` part of `INSERT INTO...FROM`.

Comment: There is an awesome utility that you can run as a command that converts VFP into SQL.  https://www.whitetown.com/winhelp/winhelp.php?product=dbf2sql   I use it to generate SQL then I use the sqlcmd to insert all the rows.